# Why does the color of a body only depend on absorptive power and not emissive power?

Tags: thermal-radiation, radiation

In the numerous explanations on nets and books, all give the reasoning as follow. If you see a red shirt, it's because that pen had a higher absorptive power for all colors except red, causing its reflection. But the body is also going to emit radiation, so why don't we consider that factor as well? Shouldn't the color we see be of wavelength corresponding to low spectral absorptive power and high spectral emissive power?

Answer (score 3):

The light emitted by object itself is negligible as compared to the visible light falling on it. However, the amount of light reflected by it is largely comparable to the brightness of the source, and is thus taken into account while determining the reason for an object's colour.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It is because color is always discussed under conditions of reflection of a light source at room temperature. Under these conditions the reflection by the object of an external light source is much stronger than the thermal emission of the object itself, in the visible range. It can be different the cases of fire and red hot iron show. Also, at room temperature, many objects emit much more than they reflect in the far infrared.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers tell you why the explanations are as they are, said explanations miss some everyday objects, where emissive power does play a role, namely those, where fluorescence plays a role.

One example are text marker marks (or most high visibility vests), they show bright "glowing" colours, because they fluoresce – that is the absorb ultraviolet and blue light and this drives emission of yellow or red light (more than is incident from the light source). This results in the intense and bright colour impression.